# Converting Properties to an Input Stream?

Tags: java, properties, sftp

Is it possible to convert a Properties to an InputStream after we modified it.

Here is a bit of code to clarify the question:

```
sftpConnection = new connectSFTP(host, user, pass, port);
Properties ssProperties = new Properties();
InputStream in = null;
try{
    in = sftpConnection.download(fileName, fileDirectory);
    ssProperties.load(in);
    //System.out.println("File Found");
    ssProperties.setProperty(key, value);
    sftpConnection.upload(<<Need the new InputStream here>>, fileDirectory);
    in.close();     
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
System.out.println("File Not Found"); 
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sure - the simplest way is to create a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, save into that, then create a `ByteArrayInputStream` around the result:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ssProperties.store(output, null);
ByteArrayInputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(output.toByteArray());
sftpConnection.upload(input, fileDirectory);
```